# Undefined index message but Ajax working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

my problem is that I have a login panel that worked only with php. Due to some changes I made to show a loading icon, and then a refresh of the page, i had to implement Ajax.

My problem begins when, for some reason, when i click the submit button the loading icon is shown and the request starts correctly but also error "indefined index" appears.

First of all this is the part of the html code for the login page:

```
<form id="formlogin"name="form1">
    <table id="tabla_usuario">
        <tr>
            <td>Usuario</td>
            <td><input id="inputlogin" type="text" size="18" name="user" style="line-height:5px;height:20px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contraseña</td>
            <td><input id="inputlogin" type="password" size="18" name="pass" style="line-height:5px;height:20px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input  type="submit" name="boton" value="Login" id="botonlogin"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The php login code is this one:

```
<?php

if($conexion->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conexion->connect_error . ']');
}
// username and password sent from form
$minombreusuario= $_POST['user'];
$micontrasena= $_POST['pass']; 
//consulta//
$sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Usuario= ? and password= ?");
if (!$sql) {
    print ("Error en prepare: " . $conexion->error . "n");
    exit;
}


if (!$sql->bind_param("ss",$minombreusuario,$micontrasena)) {
    print("Error en bind_param: " . $sql->error . "n");
    exit;
}
if (!$sql->execute()) {
echo "Falló la ejecución: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
}
$sql->store_result();
if ($sql->num_rows==1) {


//Inicio session//
$_SESSION['usuari'] = $_POST['user'];

}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

And then this is the ajax js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#botonlogin').on('click',function(e){


e.preventDefault();


var datos = $('#formlogin').serialize();

$.ajax({

url:'checklogin.php',
data: datos,
type: 'POST',
success: function() {
window.location.reload(true);
}

});

});

});
```

Finally the script for the loading to be shown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#contenedor_carga").on("ajaxStart", function(){
$(this).show(); 
   }).on("ajaxStop", function(){
$(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Don't know where I am wrong and I apologize for the large amount of code, hope you can help me solve the problem.

Comment: hmm. Could you list the entire text of the error you get?

Comment: Probably not related, but I noticed you are using sessions and I don't see `session_start();` in your code. *(Most leave that out, because they feel it's just not that important).* - it is.

Comment: Yes, the entire error is this one. Notice: Undefined index: user in F:\xampp-portable\htdocs\checklogin.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: pass in F:\xampp-portable\htdocs\checklogin.php on line 17
 Wrong Username or Password

And it's not because of session_start(); cause i solved this auto starting the session.

Comment: @JaviMuñozTous Then put `session_start();` at the top under `<?php` and it should work. That's why you need it in all your pages involved. Or are you saying that you do have `session_start();` included inside ALL your pages?

Comment: You should also consider using the `isset()` function to check if `$_POST` is actually set, before trying to assign it to a variable.

Comment: Fred I have the php.ini changed so my session starts auto. That is not the problem but thanks. One more detail is that the error is there until the Ajax success runs the refresh page function. Then the session it's started, so the login works.

Comment: @JaviMuñozTous Ok. I Google'd this and found that `"ajaxStart"` and `"ajaxStop"` should not be inside double quotes. Try removing them all and try again.

Comment: Didn't worked yet but nothing changed so you must be true. I'll continue trying.